# JavaScript, P5.JS, Canvas - Размер канвы и странности метода rect()

Tags: javascript, canvas

Использую библиотеку P5.JS чтобы нарисовать квадрат шириной и высотой во всю канву:

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(100,100);
    background(200,200,200);
}

function draw() {
    rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
}
```

Согласно справочнику P5, 100 в моем методе **rect()** - это ширина и высота прямоугольника.
Тогда почему мой квадрат выходит за пределы канвы и я не вижу двух его сторон?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если поменять на `rect(0, 0, 99, 99)` то квадрат занимает всю канву.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тогда может показаться, что 99 - это координаты противоположного угла,
но это не так, это именно длина и ширина.

Comment: Не уверен, но, думаю, что это просто рамка квадрата не влезает

Comment: Получается, что левая и верхняя рамка являются частью квадрата, а правая и нижняя нет. Иначе мы бы не видели ни одной из них. Странно.

Comment: Да нет, почему же. Просто левая и верхняя рамки строятся **от** граней холста. В частности, такая же ситуация и с простыми DOM-элементами. Если не мудрить с CSS свойством `box-sizing`, то квадрат со стороной 100px и рамками толщиной 100px будет на самом деле не 100 на 100, а 300 на 300, и если ограничить область видимости сотней пикселей, то ничего кроме левой и верхней рамок вы не увидите.

Comment: Нет, я, конечно, не утверждаю, что проблема именно в этом. Я не знаком ни с P5, ни тем более с его API, просто предполагаю из наиболее очевидного. Вполне возможно (хотя и маловероятно), что проблема на самом деле кроется в неправильной документации.

Comment: Ясно, значит контур не является частью квадрата. И тогда, для отображения контура квадрат нужно чуть сдвинуть вправо и вниз. Спасибо.